# How to click a button that doesn't have an ID using jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console

I would like to run some code in the Chrome console so that a button would be clicked. I done a bit of research on how to do this, but all the results I found achieved this by using the button's id. However, I can't find the ID of this button and I don't think it has one.

Here is the source code (the button is highlighted)
[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLtsM.png)

All help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please copy+paste your code in to the question. Images are next to useless. With regard to you issue, you can use a class (or combination thereof) to select your required element

Comment: Simply use its class? $('.btn-class-here')

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: if it's the highlighted button then you can directly access it via `btn-play` class which is unique as mentioned in my answer below. it will take less time as its more specified.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: Do you want to click the button by entering a console command? Or do you want to define what happens when you click the button? Anyway, try `document.querySelector("#maincard .btn-play")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the button using class `btn-play`

```
 1. javascript example
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-play")[0]; 
    elem.addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("clicked");
    },false);

2. Jquery example 
   $(".btn-play").click(function(){
alert("clicked");
});

if you want to trigger click on the button then use below 
$(".btn-play").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parent div with the id 'maincard' can be used with jquery to select that button. look at the example below. Using nth-child you can select which button you want to use. Currently it is selecting the last button from the image.

```
$("#maincard button:nth-child(2)").on("click", function() {
   //Do Stuff here


  });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated my answer

Comment: thanks for the reply. I ran this in the console and I got the following error: http://prntscr.com/g89xsb (please see screenshot)

Comment: @qttqtt oh, that just means that the semi colon is missing at the end, check updated answer.

Comment: I tried the updated one, no errors. However, it doesn't click the button and it says this in console: http://prntscr.com/g89ynf I'm new to coding so sorry if seems like a stupid question.

Comment: @qttqtt I would suggest you read upon how jquery works. I would start here, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ and to see how click events work in Jquery look here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can try to find your button:

```
$("#maincard").find(".uk-button.uk-button-default.btn-play.uk-button-large.uk-width-small");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click a button using class name.

Example:

```
<input type="button" class="btnClass" value="Click Me" />

$('.btnClass').click(function(){
    alert('Clicked');
});
```